I want to pass two parameters, but when using parentheses (), I can't do it anymore
I am not very familiar with the use of single quotation marks, and it seems that I will not bind Workbook with () passing. I want to pass at least two character parameters
Sub 宏1()
    S = 1
    K = 2
    
    Application.OnTime Now, "'宏2 (" & S & ")'": Exit Sub
    'Application.OnTime Now, "'宏2 ("" & S & ""','"" & K & "")'": Exit Sub
    'Application.OnTime Now, "'宏2 ("" & S & "","" & K & "")'": Exit Sub
    'Application.OnTime Now, "'宏2 ("" & S & ""','"" & K & "")'": Exit Sub
    'Application.OnTime Now, "'宏2 ('"" & S & ""','"" & K & ""')'": Exit Sub
    'Application.OnTime Now, "'宏2 (" & S & "," & K & ")'": Exit Sub
    'Application.OnTime Now, "宏2 ("" & S & ""','"" & K & "")": Exit Sub
    'Application.OnTime Now, "宏2 (" & S & "','" & K & ")": Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub 宏2(Optional ByVal A As String, Optional ByVal B As String)
    Debug.Print A, B
    Stop
End Sub


You may have a look onto this question.

Avoid using non-English characters as macro names. Stack Overflow users who attempt to assist you may encounter difficulties running the macro in their Office environment.

First thing you need to understand is how a regular call to a Sub works in VBA. (Note that I renamed your subroutine to S2)
You can either use
S2 s, k

Or
Call S2(s, k)

If you use the following syntax:
S2 (s)

The parenthensis around s have nothing to do with the call of the subroutine. They force VBA to "evaluate" the value in parenthensis and create a copy of the value. As the consequence
S2 (s, k)   

throws a syntax error because VBA cannot evaluate a term like (s, k)

Now coming back to the Application.OnTime. The call needs to substitute the variable names with their actual value, enclosed with quote characters
S2 "1", "2"

This can be created with
"s2 """ & s & """,""" & k & """"

which looks quite confusing: If you want to put a quote character into a string, you need to double it. It may get more obvious if you use the following syntax:
Const quote = """"  ' Now quote contains a string with a single quote 
"s2 " & quote & s & quote & "," & quote & k & quote

Now the last step is that you need to put the whole expression into single quotes when you use it in Application.OnTime
Application.OnTime Now, "'s2 " & quote & s & quote & ", " & quote & k & quote & "'"


3Q，thanks，Unable to pass more than one parameter within parentheses, I have given up
